# non-working relative **unicode** links in markdown in github

Tags: unicode, utf-8, github

I forked [repo](https://github.com/csswizardry/CSS-Guidelines) and [translate it](https://github.com/matmuchrapna/CSS-Guidelines/blob/master/README%20Russian.md) to my native language.

There is no problem with original table of contents in english readme file — there are **working**  relative links from table of contents to headings in file itself.
[image]

My translation file with equal structure has no such linked headings.
[image].

I notices that english links work as well, in opposite to unicode links:
[image]

**What is problem? Why table of content in my readme file is not working?**